# Object not being found second time

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

This is something I do all the time...i'm sure it's just early morning syndrome but I can't see what's wrong here.

The same object is being set in different ways but the second time I can't see to reference it.

Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="rptSecondTab" OnItemDataBound="rptSecondTab_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="divIcon" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" class="tab-pane overflow-auto">
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code:

```
((HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("divIcon")).ID = NavURL;

if (secondFirstRun)
{
  ((HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("divIcon")).Attributes.Add("class", "active tab-pane overflow-auto");
}
```

Setting the ID works fine but setting the active attribute falls over with:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

On the attribute adding line

Comment: Where does the data come from? Is there no data bound on the second attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the id of control, which probably is not required, and lster accessing the control with the old id. you would use `NavURL` instead of `divIcon`. You better store the divIcon in some object and later use it.

```
HtmlGenericControl htmlGenericControl = ((HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("divIcon")).ID = NavURL;

if (secondFirstRun)
{
      htmlGenericControl .Attributes.Add("class", "active tab-pane overflow-auto");
}
```